Incorrect/Different Polish month names generated from date/fns package
I am using date-fns(v3.6.0) to render the month names in a react native app. The Polish ones seem to be different from the usual month names from a Google search/ChatGPT result.
My implementation of the date-fns looks like
export const getMonthName = (date: Date) => {
  if (date.getFullYear() === startOfToday().getFullYear()) {
    return format(date, 'MMMM', { locale: 'pl' });
  } else {
    return format(date, 'MMMM yyyy', { locale:'pl' });
  }
};

This returns the month names as

stycznia
lutego
marca
kwietnia
maja
czerwca
lipca
sierpnia
września
...

however the google search for months names in Polish is

January in Polish is styczeń
February in Polish is luty
March in Polish is marzec
April in Polish is kwiecień
May in Polish is maj
June in Polish is czerwiec
July in Polish is lipiec
August in Polish is sierpień
September in Polish is wrzesień
October in Polish is październik
November in Polish is listopad
December in Polish is grudzień

I found out this github link for the issue on the date/fns github repository which says that the month names are now fixed in v3.6.0

I don't speak Polish, but those seem to be the same words in a different case, presumably the correct one for saying in that month.
